# How to restore Ctrl+M,O behaviour in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2017

In VS2015 and before, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>O</kbd> would collapse all constructors, methods, properties in a file. It would also collapse all regions.

In VS2017 it no longer collapses the regions.

I really liked the high level view that this keyboard chord produced, with collapsed regions. In VS2017 that chord will actually *expand* all regions too.

You can invoke <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>L</kbd> twice, but this collapses *everything* which makes it impossible to see anything.

Is there a way of getting the old behaviour back?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Seems like there's a solution for it [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25467/collapse-to-definitions-doesnt-collapse-regions.html)
If I understood you right

> It seems that this behavior still exists within visual studio 2017 except it is turned off by default. It can be enabled under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> Outlining -> "Collapse #regions when collapsing to definitions"

[image]